# MVVM Respository

Tags: kotlin, mvvm

i have a error on code that says

**overload resolution ambiguity. all these functions match**

```
class MovieRespository (val apiService: ApiService, val movieDao: MovieDao) {
    fun getListMovie() = movieDao.streamAll()
            .onErrorResumeNext{
                apiService.getMyMovie()
                        .doOnSuccess {
                            if (it.results.isEmpty()){
                            }else{
                                movieDao.deleteAll()
                                it.results.let {
                                    Timber.d("input data")
                                    val semuadata = it.map { data -> Movie.from(data) }
                                    movieDao.insert(semuadata)
                                }
                            }
                        }
            }
}
```

also there something like this in my error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMWVB.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to specify the parameter you take in `onErrorResumeNext`:

```kotlin
i have a error on code that says

overload resolution ambiguity. all these functions match

class MovieRespository (val apiService: ApiService, val movieDao: MovieDao) {
    fun getListMovie() = movieDao.streamAll()
            .onErrorResumeNext{ next: Publisher<List<Movie>> ->
                apiService.getMyMovie()
                        .doOnSuccess {
                            if (it.results.isEmpty()){
                            }else{
                                movieDao.deleteAll()
                                it.results.let {
                                    Timber.d("input data")
                                    val semuadata = it.map { data -> Movie.from(data) }
                                    movieDao.insert(semuadata)
                                }
                            }
                        }
            }
}
```

Comment: i did and still have some error like this

None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.

onErrorResumeNext(**Function<in Throwable!, out Publisher<out List<Movie>!>!>!**) defined in io.reactivex.Flowable
onErrorResumeNext(**Publisher<out List<Movie>!>!**) defined in io.reactivex.Flowable